# How can I tell GAE to cache external images

Tags: java, html, google-app-engine

I need the use browser caching for external images that have urls that do not end in an extension

The image url looks something like this `http://website.com/?imageId=45454`

I have the following appengine-web.xml but the images still load from the website everytime

```
<static-files>
        <include path="http://website.com/*"  expiration="7d" />

        <include path="/**.gif" expiration="7d" />
        <include path="/**.png" expiration="7d" />
        <include path="/**.jpg" expiration="7d" />
        <include path="/**.ico" expiration="7d" />
        <include path="/**.js" expiration="7d" />
        <include path="/**.css"  expiration="1d" />
        <include path="/robots.txt"  expiration="7d"/>
        <include path="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Questrial"  expiration="7d"/>
        <include path="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,600"  expiration="7d"/>
    </static-files>
```

Comment: The fonts line does nothing - you can remove it. A browser will request this resource from fonts.googleapis.com, and all the headers on a response will be set by fonts.googleapis.com, which your appengine-web.xml has nothing to do with.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do it in appengine-web.xml settings. Instead, you should instruct your servlet, which processes this request, to set the correct headers on a response when it returns an image, telling the browser that this image is cacheable.

Comment: How can I do that? I use the url in the img src not in the servlet

Comment: There must be a servlet in you r project that is called when `http://website.com/?imageId=45454` request hits your instance. This servlet returns the image to the browser.

Comment: the image server is not mine. all i am doing is including the urls in my img tag in the html/jsp

Comment: Sorry, it's not your decision then - the owner of the images decides if they should be cached or not.